# Gnuradio C++ analog python block rational_resampler_fff

Tags: c++, gnuradio

In gnuradio-companion I use filter block  rational_resampler_fff.
This block written using Python. I test grc and I want use flowgraph in C++ app.
How I can use python block in C++?